# Update Column from another column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

we need to update our mail addresses in a table, because we have a new domain-part. The local-part remains untouched

In the table is a column for Name, Surname and Mail. (And other columns which are not important).

We want it to look like this in the end:

```
Name    Surname     Mail
Test    Name        Test.Name@newdomain.com
Test2   Name2       Test2.Name2@newdomain.com
```

But while trying to do so we broke it and now the mail column only shows the new domain. We used the following code:

```
update table
set mail = Replace('olddomain.com','newdomain.com')
where mail LIKE '%olddomain.com'
```

So now we need to restore the mail column and add the new domain-part. Any help?

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised this works.  Normally, `replace()` takes three arguments:

```
set mail = Replace(mail, 'olddomain.com', 'newdomain.com')
```

I might suggest that you include the `@` in the logic as well.

Answer (score 1):

replace() takes three arguments

```
update table
set mail = Replace(mail,'@olddomain.com','@newdomain.com')
where mail LIKE '%olddomain.com'
```